# Writing parquet file throws...An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified

Tags: parquet, azure-databricks, azure-blob-storage, spark-notebook

I have two ADLSv2 storage accounts, both are hierarchical namespace enabled.
In my Python Notebook, I'm reading a CSV file from one storage account and writing as parquet file in another storage, after some enrichment.

I am getting below error when writing the parquet file...

```
StatusCode=400, An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is my Notebook code snippet...

```
# Databricks notebook source
# MAGIC %python
# MAGIC 
# MAGIC STAGING_MOUNTPOINT = "/mnt/inputfiles"
# MAGIC if STAGING_MOUNTPOINT in [mnt.mountPoint for mnt in dbutils.fs.mounts()]:
# MAGIC   dbutils.fs.unmount(STAGING_MOUNTPOINT)
# MAGIC 
# MAGIC PERM_MOUNTPOINT = "/mnt/outputfiles"
# MAGIC if PERM_MOUNTPOINT in [mnt.mountPoint for mnt in dbutils.fs.mounts()]:
# MAGIC   dbutils.fs.unmount(PERM_MOUNTPOINT)

STAGING_STORAGE_ACCOUNT = "--------"
STAGING_CONTAINER = "--------"
STAGING_FOLDER = --------"
PERM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT = "--------"
PERM_CONTAINER = "--------"

configs = {
 "fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
 "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": 
 "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
 "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "#####################",
 "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="DemoScope",key="DemoSecret"),
 "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": 
 "https://login.microsoftonline.com/**********************/oauth2/token"}

STAGING_SOURCE = 
"abfss://{container}@{storage_acct}.blob.core.windows.net/".format(container=STAGING_CONTAINER, 
storage_acct=STAGING_STORAGE_ACCOUNT)

try:
 dbutils.fs.mount(
  source=STAGING_SOURCE,
  mount_point=STAGING_MOUNTPOINT,
  extra_configs=configs)
except Exception as e:
 if "Directory already mounted" in str(e):
 pass # Ignore error if already mounted.
else:
 raise e

print("Staging Storage mount Success.")

inputDemoFile = "{}/{}/demo.csv".format(STAGING_MOUNTPOINT, STAGING_FOLDER)
readDF = (spark
          .read.option("header", True)
          .schema(inputSchema)
          .option("inferSchema", True)
          .csv(inputDemoFile))

LANDING_SOURCE = 
 "abfss://{container}@{storage_acct}.blob.core.windows.net/".format(container=LANDING_CONTAINER, 
 storage_acct=PERM_STORAGE_ACCOUNT)

try:
 dbutils.fs.mount(
 source=PERM_SOURCE,
 mount_point=PERM_MOUNTPOINT,
 extra_configs=configs)
except Exception as e:
 if "Directory already mounted" in str(e):
  pass # Ignore error if already mounted.
 else:
  raise e

print("Landing Storage mount Success.")

outPatientsFile = "{}/patients.parquet".format(outPatientsFilePath)
print("Writing to parquet file: " + outPatientsFile)

***Below call is failing…error is 
StatusCode=400
StatusDescription=An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.
ErrorCode=
ErrorMessage=***

(readDF
 .coalesce(1)
 .write
 .mode("overwrite")
 .option("header", "true")
 .option("compression", "snappy")
 .parquet(outPatientsFile)
)
```

Comment: Hi. If you use Azure blob storage in databricks, you should use `wasbs` protocol to access blob : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage

Comment: I'm using abfss, since hierarchical namespace was enabled.

Comment: Hi. Since you use Azure data lake gen2.  the url should be like `abfss://<file-system-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/`. Please change it and try again.

Comment: That was it, thx

Answer (score 1):

I summarize the solution as below.

If you want to mount Azure data lake storage gen2 as Azure databricks file system, the URL should be like `abfss://<file-system-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2#--mount-an-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-account-using-a-service-principal-and-oauth-20)

For example

1. Create an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 account.

```
az login
az storage account create \
    --name <account-name> \
    --resource-group <group name> \
    --location westus \
    --sku Standard_RAGRS \
    --kind StorageV2 \
    --enable-hierarchical-namespace true
```

2. Create a service principal and assign Storage Blob Data Contributor to the sp in the scope of the Data Lake Storage Gen2 storage account

```
az login

az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" \
    --scopes /subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>
```

3. mount Azure data lake gen2 in Azure databricks(python)

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "<appId>",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": "<clientSecret>",
       "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/token",
       "fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization": "true"}

dbutils.fs.mount(
source = "abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/folder1",
mount_point = "/mnt/flightdata",
extra_configs = configs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of important points to note while mounting Storage accounts in Azure Databricks.

> For **Azure Blob storage**: `source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<directory-name>"`

> For **Azure Data Lake Storage gen2**: `source = "abfss://<file-system-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/"`

To mount an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 filesystem or a folder inside it as Azure Databricks file system, the URL should be like `abfss://<file-system-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/`

[image]

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks - Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2)